Pandas перебрать строки в 2х DataFrame и изменить 2 колонки
У меня есть 2 DataFrame: 1. продукты, 2. остатки по дням
Я пытаюсь:

перебрать продукты по колонке "Artical" из "prod_df" в "sales_df"
для каждого найденного продукта изменить количество "Start_of_Day" и "End_of_Day"


если дата меньше "report_start" минус 1 день, то "Start_of_Day" и "End_of_Day" равны "Qty"
если нет, то "Start_of_Day" равна "End_of_Day" предыдущего дня, а "End_of_Day" равна "Qty"

В результате я хочу получить DataFrame, как на картинке. Но получаю DataFrame, в котором "Start_of_Day" и "End_of_Day" равны 0
Как заменить значения?

Вот то, что я пробовала:
mport pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

report_start = '01.06.2024'
report_start = pd.to_datetime(report_start, format='%d.%m.%Y',errors='coerce')
report_end = '04.06.2024'
report_end = pd.to_datetime(report_end, format='%d.%m.%Y',errors='coerce')

prod_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Artical': ['111', '222', '333', '444'],
    'Name': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'],
})

sales_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Artical': ['111', '111', '111', '111', '111', '222', '222', '222', '222', '222'],
    'Date': ['31.05.2024', '01.06.2024', '02.06.2024', '03.06.2024', '04.06.2024', '31.05.2024', '01.06.2024', '02.06.2024', '03.06.2024', '04.06.2024'],
    'Qty': ['2172', '2172', '2172', '2128', '2128', '0', '2068', '2068', '2056', '2056']    
})
frames = []
for i in prod_df['Artical']:
    data = sales_df[(sales_df['Artical'] == str(i))].reset_index(drop=True)
    data['Start_of_Day'] = 0
    data['End_of_Day'] = 0
    if data.empty == False:
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            if row['Date'] == (report_start - timedelta(days=1)):
                row['Start_of_Day'] = row['Qty']
                row['End_of_Day'] = row['Qty']
                # row['qtyStart_of_Day'] = row['qtyStart_of_Day'].replace(0, row['Qty'])
                print(row)
            else:
                new_qty = data[(data['Date'] == (report_start - timedelta(days=1)))].reset_index(drop=True)
                row['Start_of_Day'] = new_qty['End_of_Day']
                row['End_of_Day'] = row['Qty']
                
            frames.append(data)
        
final_df = pd.concat(frames, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(final_df)


"если нет, то "Start_of_Day" равна "End_of_Day" предыдущего дня"- а если предыдущего дня нет (первая дата для этого артикула), тогда что? А вообще вам нужно понять, как "векторно" одним чохом задать все значения в подходящих строках. Перебирать через iterrows - очень медленно и вообще тупиковая ветвь эволюции.

@CrazyElf предыдущий день есть всегда (с значением Qty либо 0, либо другое), потому что изначально база строиться на весь период работы компании, а первый год работы для этих целей мы не берем. К сожалению, я далеко не профи в Python, поэтому честно не понимаю о чем вы :( "вам нужно понять, как "векторно" одним чохом задать все значения"

Ну вот вам пример "векторного" подхода с комментариями
# преобразование строк в даты
report_start = pd.to_datetime(report_start, dayfirst=True)
sales_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales_df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
# сортируем, чтобы артикулы и даты были упорядочены
sales_df = sales_df.sort_values(['Artical', 'Date'])
# End_of_Day одинаковый при всех условиях
sales_df['End_of_Day'] = sales_df['Qty']
# строки, где начинается новый артикл
article_change = (sales_df['Artical'] != sales_df.shift()['Artical'])
# маска, по которой будем по-разному заполнять данные
old_mask = ((sales_df['Date'] - report_start).dt.days <= -1) | article_change
# фильтр по маске
sales_df.loc[old_mask, 'Start_of_Day'] = sales_df['Qty']
# фильтр по отрицанию маски
sales_df.loc[~old_mask, 'Start_of_Day'] = sales_df.shift()['End_of_Day']
# колонки переставляем в нужном порядке
sales_df = sales_df[['Artical', 'Date', 'Qty', 'Start_of_Day', 'End_of_Day']]


Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ! Все работает!
